# How to avoid replication lag in case all writes on master and reads on replica?

Tags: mysql, replication, percona, master-slave-replication, proxysql

I have stuck with the replication lag problem. I am trying to refactor my DB infrastructure.
The first step was read-write split. I used ProxySQL то implement it. Now I have masterDb where all INSERT and UPDATES executing and 2 replicas where I route all SELECT.

But the main problem I faced with, replication lag. Because usually when you change something in DB you immediately read data and expect to have new data in the query result, but with replication lag, I receive outdated data. After googling I found this article https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/11/29/mysql-high-availability-stale-reads-and-how-to-fix-them/ and according to this info the best option in 2018 was "ProxySQL 2.0 GTID consistent reads"

Any updates from 2018?  Maybe you guys know a better solution? Please share!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some `SELECTs` exist to support the Inserts/Updates/Deletes that you are about to do.  You *must not* send them to the Replica; they *must* be done in the Primary, usually inside the same transaction with the write operation.  Check to see that ProxySQL is not doing that.

Aside from what Bill mentions, other tricks are possible.  By inserting something into the replication stream and then checking it on the Replica, you may be able to see if your writes have made it to the Replica.  This worked fine before replication became multi-threaded.  So beware of old advice that suggests this trick.

You may as well plan on changing your application to at least have two ways to connect -- either through a Proxy versus deliberately going to the Primary.

Another gotcha -- Any check of a Replica's freshness must be in the same connection with the `SELECT` you are about to do.  This is because a different connection may hit a different Replica.  Replicas are not necessarily equally fresh.  (A big `SELECT` one one Replica can, in many ways, slow down replication.)

**Galera**

Since you are already running with 3 servers, you may as well consider switching to Percona PXC (or MySQL 5.7 + Galera, or MariaDB with Galera built-in).  It provides a 'wsrep' method *at the `SELECT` level* for making sure the data is synced up.  Meanwhile, it provides better HA support, automated failover, and (optionally) writing to any node.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes, actually we configured to route all SELECT FOR UPDATE queries to the master. And what do you think about "5) ProxySQL 2.0 GTID consistent reads" from this article https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/11/29/mysql-high-availability-stale-reads-and-how-to-fix-them/

Comment: @VolodymyrBilovus - Good article.  First, make sure you have a new-enough version (or are using Galera) to have GTIDs / wsrep / etc.  What version are you running?

Comment: Currently it's 5.7.3 and It looks like it will be easy to update to the 5.7.5 (which is necessary)

Comment: I would go to at least the GA release of 5.7.9, but you may as well go to the "latest" 5.7, namely 5.7.36 (or perhaps newer).  Anyway, 5.7.xx has GTIDs, etc.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilovus - See what I added to my Answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update! We will investigate this way.

Answer (score 4):

Replication always has lag, if only a very small amount, because your data changes are not even written to the binary log until you commit a transaction. Then the replica has to download those events in the binary log and apply them on the replica instance. This is normally very quick, but by definition, it is > 0 lag for every event.

It is also possible for your application to attempt to read data it just wrote, *before* it commits its own transaction. In that case, there's no way the replica can have the same change, since it hasn't even been committed on the source instance yet.

If your app needs absolutely current data, with no possibility of reading stale data, then the queries must read from the source instance, not a replica.

But not every read needs to read such strictly current data. Each query in your application has potentially different sensitivity to reading data that is lagging a little bit behind the source.

I wrote a presentation [Read Write Splitting with MySQL and PHP](https://www.percona.com/resources/technical-presentations/readwrite-splitting-mysql-and-php-percona-mysql-webinars) for Percona, which describes several different solutions for different levels of replication lag tolerance.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! And what do you think about  "5) ProxySQL 2.0 GTID consistent reads" from this article https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/11/29/mysql-high-availability-stale-reads-and-how-to-fix-them/

Comment: I haven't used it. It sounds like it could work, but in general, expecting too much to happen "transparently" is not wise. And as I point out in my presentation, it's not necessary to be so strict about replication lag in many cases.

Comment: BTW Thanks, man!